# Embed gnuplot inside existing QtWidget

Tags: c++, windows, qt, gnuplot

I am creating a (pseudo) real-time plotting application in C++, using gnuplot as my backend for plotting. One of my requirements is that the plot must be inside an existing window, instead of having a separate plot window (which gnuplot defaults to).

Gnuplot has an option to specify the (Qt) widget ID which seems like this would fit my use case:

```
set terminal qt widget <id>
```

I tried passing the value inside my `QtWidget::effectiveWinId()` to no avail.

*Update*: Tried using the internal value of the window id `QtWidget::winId()` with no luck as well.

**The problem is that I cannot find any documentation on what `<id>` is supposed to be.  Is this what the developers of gnuplot intended?**

Here's an example of my code:

```
#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QWidget>
#include <QtNetwork/QLocalSocket>

int main()
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QWidget win(nullptr, Qt::Window);
    QWidget *window = win.window();
    win.show();
    std::cout << "effective win id: " << window->effectiveWinId() << "\n";
    std::cout << "effective win id: " << win.effectiveWinId() << "\n";
    return app.exec();
}
```

In gnuplot:

```
gnuplot> set term qt widget <value from effectiveWinId>
gnuplot> plot x
Could not connect to existing qt widget. Starting a new one.
```

Comment: Take a look at [https://github.com/gnuplot/gnuplot/tree/master/src/qtterminal](https://github.com/gnuplot/gnuplot/tree/master/src/qtterminal). There is an example on how to embedding gnuplot window to your application.

Comment: @putu I also saw this but was unable to get it working because of the lack of instructions. I've tried using `qmake` but it seems the `QtGnuplot.pro` file is not configured to create this embedded example. I am fairly new to the Qt ecosystem so is there something that I am missing?