# How to embed gnuplot qt in pyqt?

Tags: python, pyqt, gnuplot

The gnuplot terminal `qt` accepts an `widget id` (http://www.bersch.net/gnuplot-doc/complete-list-of-terminals.html#qt).
How can I use this id number to embed gnuplot qt window into an pyqt5 application? I would appreciate a minimal working code.

A similar question for c++ has no answer ([Embed gnuplot inside existing QtWidget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45703258/embed-gnuplot-inside-existing-qtwidget)).

For comparison, with `tcl/tk` (program `wish`) + `x11` terminal the following works

```
set unit [open "| gnuplot 2>@1" w+]  
frame .x11 -bg "white" -width 640 -height 450
button .b1 -text "some button"
pack .x11 .b1

puts $unit "set term x11 window '[winfo id .x11]'"
flush $unit

puts $unit "pl sin(x)"
flush $unit
```

[image]

Comment: c++ question has answer - the first comment

Comment: @mugiseyebrows Technically not an answer but a comment

Comment: But how does it look in pyqt?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a QProcess to send the commands, and in those commands pass the window id to it:

```py
import sys
from functools import cached_property

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class GnuPlotManager(QtCore.QObject):
    @cached_property
    def process(self):
        qprocess = QtCore.QProcess()
        qprocess.setProgram("gnuplot")
        return qprocess

    def start(self):
        self.process.start()

    def send_command(self, command):
        self.process.write((command + "\n").encode())


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Send Command")

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(central_widget)
        lay.addWidget(self.command_le)
        lay.addWidget(button)
        lay.addWidget(self.container)

        button.clicked.connect(self.handle_clicked)

        self.gnuplot_manager.start()
        self.gnuplot_manager.send_command("set terminal qt")
        wid = int(self.container.winId())
        self.gnuplot_manager.send_command(f"set term x11 window '{wid:x}'")

        self.gnuplot_manager.send_command("clear")

        self.command_le.setText("pl sin(x)")

        self.resize(640, 480)

    @cached_property
    def container(self):
        return QtWidgets.QWidget()

    @cached_property
    def command_le(self):
        return QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

    @cached_property
    def gnuplot_manager(self):
        return GnuPlotManager()

    def handle_clicked(self):
        self.gnuplot_manager.send_command(self.command_le.text())
        self.updateGeometry()


def main(args):
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(args)

    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()

    ret = app.exec_()
    sys.exit(ret)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looks good. Yet, I get `ImportError: cannot import name 'cached_property'`.

Comment: @Friedrich What version of python do you use? If you use a version lower than python 3.8 then you must install `backports.cached-property`: `python -m pip install backports.cached-property` and change `from functools import cached_property` to `from backports.cached_property import cached_property`

Comment: I have Python 3.6.9. The `cached_property` error is gone with your help. The `x11` window however is not drawn into the qt app (maybe too fast?). Will it work also with `qt` terminal?

Comment: @Friedrich What do you mean by *qt terminal*? Have you pressed the button?

Comment: gnuplot's `qt` terminal is described in http://www.bersch.net/gnuplot-doc/complete-list-of-terminals.html#qt. Then in your code `set term x11 window '{wid:x}'` likely should be replaced by `set term qt widget '{wid:x}'`

Comment: And yes, I have pressed the button and commands are send, but the x11 window is separate.

Comment: @Friedrich What is your OS and how did you install gnuplot? I want to analyze why my code works for me but not for you

Comment: I have gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 2 and openSUSE Leap 15.0. I don't know how gnuplot was installed. It was just there. zypper lists gnuplot as installed.

Comment: @Friedrich According to what I understand from the docs of "set term qt" is that it allows to give an id to each window (for example id = 0, id = 1, etc) in order to be able to manipulate it easily, that is different from the window id so. The idea is to analyze why my solution does not work in your case

Comment: @Friedrich I have used a docker with opensuse and my code works, could you tell me how you installed pyqt5?

Comment: It is located in `~.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PyQt5`. Thus it was a pip user install. Files have the date 2020-06-11.

Comment: @Friedrich What version of pyqt5 did you install?

Comment: PyQt5 has no `__version__` attribute. So how can I figure this out?

Comment: @Friedrich what is the output of `python3 -c "from PyQt5.QtCore import PYQT_VERSION_STR; print('PyQt5 version', PYQT_VERSION_STR)"`?

Comment: `PyQt5 version 5.9.2`

Comment: I ran a trimmed version of your code to provide just the widget id `4000005`. Then I started a separate gnuplot session. Typing `set term qt widget '0x4000005'; pl x` I obtained 
`Terminal type is now 'qt'
Options are '0 font "Sans,9" widget "0x4000005"'
Could not connect to existing qt widget. Starting a new one.
Could not connect to existing gnuplot_qt. Starting a new one.`

Comment: @Friedrich Have you read my previous comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67368921/how-to-embed-gnuplot-qt-in-pyqt/67369621?noredirect=1#comment119083378_67369621? The option "qt widget" does not serve to establish a window Id but let's say you want to show 4 plots and each plot in a window, how do you configure each window? Well, gnuplot allows you to associate an id: `set term qt widget 0` `set term qt widget 1` `set term qt widget 2` `set term qt widge3`, and then you can modify the properties using that id.

Comment: I saw it, yet I'm not sure if I understood you. In the docs the `widget` is not explained. With `set term qt n`, i.e. __window__ number, a new qt window pops up. For `set term qt widget ID`, i.e. a __widget__ number, my guess was that it will draw into an existing qt frame (similar as in x11).

Comment: @Friedrich I just tested in docker with opensuse where I have installed gnuplot and pyqt5 5.9.2 and my code works correctly.

Comment: @Friedrich mmm, let me review what you point out, maybe I misunderstood how that command works

Comment: @Friedrich As I have just reviewed the source code, I see that this "id" is not window Id, but the name of a QLocalServer that allows 2 processes to communicate: the one from gnuplot terminal and the one from the window that gnuplot uses, that is, that "id" is the one you put when you use the https://github.com/gnuplot/gnuplot/blob/master/src/qtterminal/README.Qt library.

Comment: Thanks for all your efforts. Yet, I a bit lost here. I don't know QLocalServer, but I guess some communication is needed. The last comment sounds like it is not possible. If that is case, I would accept an updated answer.